# Ambiguous column name 'id' in result set column descriptions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables, `x` and `y`. Both these tables have an `id` column. I am trying to join content from `y_table` and `x_table` with `id` to select the correct row (`x` stores extra info about `y`, so my function should join all relevant info from x that relates to `y.id`) I assume this is why I'm getting Ambiguous column name error. However, I cannot figure out where an alias needs to be implemented to solve this error? I have tried to alias one of the tables but this doesn't seem to help.

`user_id` is a integer provided in the function parameters

```
join = self.y_table.join(self.x_table, self.y_table.c.id == self.x_table.c.user_id)
print(join)

query = select([self.y_table, self.x_table]).select_from(join).where(self.y_table.c.id == user_id)
```

Comment: At the very end, you have the following: (self.y_table.c.id == user_id)

The last user_id is ambiguous

Comment: Thanks for the comment Doom. user_id is an arguement from the function, would this still cause it to be ambiguous ? i.e. def get_y_with_x(self, user_id: int)

Comment: not sure. i see this is python, which is not my wheelhouse. in other frameworks, we are able to throw "this" in front to clarify what we are talking about. there may be something similar for you. so: this.user_id might be the way to specify the function's parameter. or use a different parameter name that cannot be confused for a column name